# Set color of treeview editing line/cell and background of check box

Tags: python, colors, treeview, gtk2

I have a treeview in Python GTK2 with custom colors set (only one in the attached images so far but will be more in time) and also a custom color set for the line selected, but my issue is when I select and toggle my first cell so I can edit the data in the line and then select a cell in that line to edit the system reverts back to the system settings as per attached images: [Selected Line color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snif0.png), [Editing Cell color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m406K.png)

I'm just wondering if anyone here knows how to access this part of the treeview so I can set the colors how I would like, and if anyone does could they share how to do this or point me in where to find the info I require.

Also another issue I have which is not a major is the color of the inside of check boxes is white, interested to know if there is a way to change this as well.

I know for both of these issues I could just set a custom system appearance but I would like to leave the system as it is and just modify these things in the program I am building.

I'm hoping someone out there can help me with my problems as I have a lot of time invested to this point and would like to not give up on this as I feel it should be achievable but it is knowing how or where to point to modify what I'm trying to do.

I have included a couple of screen shots to show what is happening, have not supplied code as at the moment it is very messy after testing tonnes of things to this point but will clean this up once I have these problems solved if I can.

I have tried a bunch of things I can think of or find to try with no luck yet, working on the common sense and trial and error methods and reading what information I can find.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.